# How to get Search Result Count in head.phtml

Tags: catalogsearch, search

I am trying to get total number of results count in head.phtml page.
I have used following code to get search term. But I am not sure how to get total number of results count here.

$term = Mage::helper('catalogsearch')->getQueryText();

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks,

Answer (score 8):

Please try bellow code

```
 if($listBlock = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('search_result_list')) {
    $productCollection = $listBlock->getLoadedProductCollection();
    echo $productCollection->getSize();
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, It is showing the product search count. Though, I noticed one thing, there is result discrepancy between to add this code or without this code.

Comment: e.g. I am trying to add the code at head.phtml file. If I don't add this code it is showing search results count 100, if I add it is showing 80

Comment: Thankks for this! I was able to use it to get the list of products outside the result.phtml :D

Comment: @Deecee2000, how to get the same in magento2?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't been able to test this, but try something like this:

```
$size = Mage::helper('catalogSearch')->getQuery()->getSearchCollection()->getSize();
```

Comment: Thanks, but it is not working as expected. It is always showing same number (10152) on all the pages, even if you are non-catalogsearch page.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but I want to share the way I get it. More simple

```
echo Mage::getSingleton('catalogsearch/layer')->getProductCollection()->count();
```